# Balancing psychics powers

Tags: magic, science-fiction

I'm GMing RPG game based on Stars Without Numbers, but its happening on my personal world. It's 36th century of our universe and humans are colonizing planets through galaxy.

I have big concerns about this world. As I didn't wanted to make psychics powers from scratch, I've just took those from RPG system itself. And there's lies problem. One of my players have power for teleportation. Right now he can teleport within 10km to place he either see directly or have been earlier (no matter how long ago). He also can teleport with himself 3 other people with their equipment. But wait, there is more, on higher levels he could teleport anywhere on planet or jump untouched from orbit to ground. All of this power isn't most OP one, but let's focus on this one particular.
I don't have problem with this exact player, as he's not that power gamer. I've got problem with idea that there should be tons of similar psychics with same power (I really don't like idea of unique psychic powers). **I need something that would stop all of those OP men and women from ruining logic of the universe with their powers.**

P.S. I've got idea of implementing extremely harsh penalties for crimes with using such powers, but I suppose it isn't too much to stop all of them.

Comment: To clarify, you are asking for a solution that would limit the powers of pour psychic humans so they won't be able to create a form of anarchy where they are above the law?

Comment: Something like that yeah, but not limit power itself, just people using it.

Comment: This seems like a better question for the RPG stack exchange, if you're looking to implement a mechanical solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be migrated to RPG.stackexchange. It appears to be a mechanical question of a TRPG.

Comment: @Halfthawed why so? I don't ask for mechanical solution, but world based one. I thought it would fit this stack.

Comment: If you want a world-based solution to *explain* a mechanic, that's one thing. However, what you're doing is looking for a way to stop the characters from being OP in a TRPG. If you gave the limitations and then asked for reasons, that would be fine, but here you're asking for both.

Answer (score 8):

**Pressure!**

Divers need to stop several minutes in order to decompress safely after some 30 meters or so. If you jump from ground level to sightsee in orbit, the decompression is naaaaasty. Lethal even.
[WIki article on the dangers of decompression.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompression_sickness)

**Inertia!**

If you teleport from a plane to solid ground, you will be a smear on the wall since your speed is 800-900 km/h.

**Crashing against other objects!**

You visited a train station and "know it". Next week you want to use your awesome ability to teleport to the same spot.....yet a wild luggage carrier appears.
Since two objects can't occupy the same space, check for damage: save for half. On a critical failure you get a nasty case of clothes wearing YOU.

In short:
it can be done and it exists. But the people who use it got a ton of pre flight checks that would make a NASA engineer proud. Since a LOT of stuff can go wrong, you do your due diligence and only jump without all that preparation if you are desperate.

Comment: In theory this teleport have guaranted safe landing, so no luggage will help. But idea with inertia isn't that bad.

Comment: Another reasonable conclusion as to WHY other people won't visit ISS on the daily is exertion. That would make popping back to the kitchen and fetch your coffee great, tactically a godsend in firefights .....yet if it tires you the same than walking the distance, you can't use it to pop from Australia to Finland without kicking the bucket.

Comment: Inertia is the key one for someone who wants to visit/return from orbit. Getting to orbit isn't hard because it's *far* (it's only an hour's drive, straight up), it's hard because you need to go *fast* (>10,000 mph).

Answer (score 4):

Exerting their powers over long periods of time or on highly complex jumps could drain their energy. They may fall unconscious or just remain weak and unable to teleport for a few days if they cross that limit.

Or maybe, overuse of their specific powers may cause it to wear out. Something akin to magical muscle tear, perhaps. To avoid ending up powerless, they restrict themselves from tearing up the universe.

Comment: Thief don't need to use his power everyday, one jump per month and he's all set up. Thats why this idea of draining energy would work.

Answer (score 3):

### Harsh Physical Consequences

Introduce a harsh consequence. Similiar to loss of energy, but impose an over-exertion that not just drains the energy but causes physical backlashes of fatal proportions. Add a nosebleed here, maybe a collapsing there, add some minor effects to the other players involved making them wary of continuous use. Over time it will be too dangerous to make multiple jumps within the same 24 hours, and the backlash will not be worth it. This will lead them to other methods and make for a more challenging game.

The human body in any state is still fragile. Too much strain on the body can lead to extreme issues.

Answer (score 2):

**Risk of interposition.**

If you can see where you are jumping, you are set.  But if I jump to my third grade classroom, what if they have rearranged the furniture?  What if I jump to my living room and the cat is sleeping where I appear?   If I am unlucky I have some sort of cat-leg hybrid beneath my knee.

I might call ahead and ask my manservant to make sure the cat is upstairs and the ottomans are all pushed back, then make the jump.  Or I can hope for the best and just jump.   If the cat and I are unlucky I have some sort of cat-leg hybrid beneath my knee.  Probably a jump into the unseen is best reserved for emergencies.

Comment: Behold my new App, SafeSpace(tm) just use the real time camera to determine if the nearest Teleportation Pod to your destination is empty and then reserve it for teleport! The app will confirm your reservation and then you can teleport without fear of fusing! Get one for your home today!

Comment: @IT Alex - I have noticed that at distances over one light minute there is noticeable lag in your app, such that a cat not present at time of confirmation might be present at time of teleportation.

Comment: @Wilik I assure you thanks to our Quantum Connection, The video feed has no such lag and you merely misinterpreted the safety of the surrounding at the time of your jump. (SafeSpace is not liable for any accidental fusions).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the availability of countermeasures: the psychic equivalent of shields, traps, mine fields, surveillance systems, etc. If you don't want to place *natural* limits on the power itself, then you have to impose *artificial* limits on the usage of powers. That way your people could still jump to any *normal* place without too much risk, but trying to jump somewhere defended could get them sent to a holding cell, bounce them back with a blistering headache, trigger an armed response from guards who can also teleport, or simply evaporate them in a puff of logic. That would mean a world where it's normal for a house to be equipped with an anti-teleport shield to keep out thieves; would that be too big of a change?

Answer (score 0):

Without reducing the users actual powers, yet still restricting them you got a few options.

Let's take most games, for it you need to use Mana to cast spells. a similar approach would allow you to limit the use of their powers without actually reducing them. Alternatively you could go with a "Blood Magic" type scenario, where each time their powers are used they suffer temporary/ permanent damage depending on what strength they sued their ability. Seeing your characters are psychic it could range from getting a slight headache for teleportation 10 KM up to getting a increased chance on getting a brain aneurysm  for teleporting to the other side of the world. This will not reduce their powers but they will be more inclined to hold back on it.

An other option would be dampening fields, natural or artificial fields created by crystals/machines that reduce the powers of psychics around them. Soldiers armed with mobile generators would be able to police psychics in a more manageable way.

Lastly what comes to mind would be predators. Creatures that feed on psychic energies and hunts their users. With the beings being drawn to them every time they use their powers. Making them spirit like ethereal beings that can only be seen by the psychic would give a nice dynamic if you ask me limiting their usefulness without actually decreasing their powers.

Answer (score 0):

A low but significant percentage chance of catastrophe ("What dimension is this anyway?"), or at least highly unexpected results would mean that such powers were only used when it's really important.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a very old tabletop RPG gamer, and I am cursed with being a GURPS fan. It suffered the same problem: some powers simply scale too fast as levels go up.

GURPS even allows more freedom when creating a character, as there are no dice rolls for it. A power gamer can create OP characters very easily. Even if there are no power gamers in the group, if the GM wishes to introduce a psionic NPC it is very easy to fall into OP territory.

So from experience, I think the solution to your particular problem is to make the teleportation power rare among NPC's. Make it so that in the whole galaxy you'd have only a handful of people with such powers, much like there were only few Jedi in Star Wars after episode 3.

Otherwise, you can introduce "teleport dampeners" as an ubiquitous technology. These reduce or negate the power of a teleporter. This also helps keep things interesting when you wish the PC's to go somewhere hard to get into, so that teleporting in cannot be used as a way to bypass all your plans.

Answer (score 0):

Quantum Scramblers.

Most inhabited planets have widespread use of cheap, ubiquitous tech which creates fields that inhibit or outright prevent the use of psychic abilities, especially high-power ones such as teleportation within a given distance of an emitter. Weak teleporters are pretty much screwed and unable to use their power inside. The most powerful, who could casually jump around the planet or to orbit, can just barely overcome the most common commercial-grade fields, although their range is severely restricted (say a 100 meters or so, at best) and it take a lot out of them. For military grade fields, forget it; they simply can't get through them, so if you need to carry out a mission where teleportation is essential, part of it is going to have to find a way of disabling the field first. Lots of roleplay potential there.

You can use the same thing for other psychic powers. In your setting, think of psychic powers as akin to hacking; even the weakest hackers can get into computer networks without any serious security, higher level hackers can get into the more secure ones, but no matter how good a hacker, it's impossible for them to get into the most secure airgapped, top of the line security and encryption, constant traffic monitoring, restricted physical access systems. They need to find another way of getting access in order to use their hacking skills.